# Create key-value in a new hash only if it is present in an old hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
conditions[:foo] = params[:foo] if params[:foo].present?
```

It will only create a key-value pair in the `conditions` hash if the key-value pair is present in `params`.

Is there a way to write it shorter?
I was thinking about [Hash#`fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch):

```
conditions[:foo] = params.fetch(:foo, nil)
```

But it is not what I want, because then I'll get a pair with `nil` value, if there is no such key in `params`.

I only need the `conditions` key-value created if such a key-value is present in `params`.

I am asking the question because I have a few similar lines of assigning, where `params[:foo]` is repeated twice on each line:

```
  conditions[:foo] = params[:foo] if params[:foo].present?
  conditions[:bar] = params[:bar] if params[:bar].present?
  conditions[:baz] = params[:baz] if params[:baz].present?
  conditions[:zxc] = params[:zxc] if params[:zxc].present?
  # ...
```

Comment: Suppose your params is `params = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}` then which keys and values you wanted to store in `conditions` ?.

Comment: If the whole point is not to repeat `params[:foo]`, you can do it with `select` and `merge!`, but it's uglier and slower.

Comment: @ndn yea, I am having few similar lines, and seeing these repeated twice on each line `params[:foo]` irritates me :)

Answer (score 3):

First off, in your original code I would use `params.key?` (unless you really don't care about cases where the value is false, empty array etc). I would probably stick with that since it is very clear and not that verbose.

One alternative I can think of:

```
conditions.merge!(params.slice(:foo))
```

This requires active support, and would stay concise even if you did this with many hash keys - you would just add them to the call to slice.

`slice` uses `has_key?` to return only the desired portion of the hash so handles values like `false` and `[]` as I suggest rather than as your question implements them.

Comment: thanks a lot! Good point with `has_key`! (Rubocop says, that `has_key` is deprecated in favor of `key`)

Comment: Slice will get `{foo: nil}` if `:foo` was not present in `params` hash - it is not equivalent to checking `present?`  OP does not want `foo: ""` either - so calling `compact` on `slice` output won't solve the problem either.

Comment: It is indeed not equivalent to calling present? - I explicitly noted that

Comment: `explicitly noted that` - where?

Comment: @FrederickCheung :-)  I don't see use of word "present" present in that last sentence of the "answer", unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need a conditional assignment, I think your first version is pretty concise.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem with your code is the repetition. Perhaps this is a bit contentious, but I would DRY it up with a lambda.

```
lAdd ->(k) { conditions[k] = params[k] if params[k].present? }

lAdd.(:foo)
lAdd.(:bar)
lAdd.(:baz)
lAdd.(:zxc)
```

Of course if you find yourself doing this in multiple places, it should be a common helper function, rather than a lambda that hardcodes the two hashes.

Comment: Ruby variables are typically lower-snake-case (`l_add`) rather than camelCase as shown here, but this is otherwise a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question because I had few similar lines of assigning, where `params[:foo]` is repeated twice on each line:

```
  conditions[:foo] = params[:foo] if params[:foo].present?
  conditions[:bar] = params[:bar] if params[:bar].present?
  conditions[:baz] = params[:baz] if params[:baz].present?
  conditions[:zxc] = params[:zxc] if params[:zxc].present?
  # ...
```

What I came up to shorten what I had is the following:

```
  %i(foo baz bar zxc).each do |value|
    conditions[value] = params[value] if params[value].present?
  end
```

But I thought it is much less readable and wanted to stick with a new line for each key-value assignment, but in shorter form.

Comment: You could create a method that would be invoked `doit(conditions, params, :foo, bar, haz, zxc)`. Incidentally, when you need four [metasyntactic variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable), `qux` (or `quux`) seems to be the #4 of choice. I've never seen `zxc`, but it does seem to work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I used `zxc` cause `qux` flew out of my head at the moment of writing :) Didn't know it is called metasyntactic variables, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternate way to do this:

```
require "active_support/all"

params = {foo: "", bar: "value", baz: nil, zxc: false}
conditions = {}

keys = %i(foo bar baz zxc)

present_params = params.slice(*keys).select{|_,v| v.present? }
conditions.merge!(present_params)
```

Comment: Although this is both longer and more complicated to read than what the OP started out with

Comment: @WandMaker my bad regarding the additional context.. Edited the question